# Running script in parallel using xargs and cat

Tags: bash, cat, xargs, parallelism

I'm inserting a lot of CSV files into database. I want to do it in parallel, for example run 4 processes. Right now I do it with the script like this:

```
find . -name "*.csv" | xargs -n 1 -P 4 ./run.sh
```

And `run.sh` cats the file to the db:

```
cat "$1" | db-client "INSERT INTO ..."
```

It seems like it works, but my question is: wouldn't cat mix up the inputs from 4 processes and does it really run in parallel or it waits till another process is done with `cat`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. never pipe `find` into `xargs` unless you're using `-print0` with `find` and `-0` with `xargs`; otherwise, file names with spaces or newlines will be your end.
2. <sup>not a use case for `cat "$1" | …`, but simply for `… < $1`.</sup> Could be written more compact, but as you like.
3. no, `cat` won't "mix up" up anything, since there's not one `cat` process, but 4, with completely isolated argument lists, and output.
4. yes, it really runs in parallel.
5. your `db-client` of course runs multiple times in parallel as well, but the whole point of a database system is that it keeps things consistent, so unless you misdesigned your `INSERT` statement to be multiple statements and not atomic, this is safe.
6. Parallelism doesn't help at all here; both your CSV file access as well as the database write access are not bounded by CPU but by inherently serialized IO underneath; so, you're not really solving a problem here. Since insertion is a write operation, and must be synchronized with other concurrent writes, parallelization probably makes things *slower*, not faster, unless you really know your database allows for sharded writes, and the bandwidth into your database server is wider than your storage read bandwidth - um, considering your question, this is unlikely.

Comment: About "$1", doesn't it use STDIN, wouldn't it be the problem in parallel scenario like this one? And about inserts, db is ClickHouse, so it did things a little faster

Comment: I don't know what you mean with "doesn't it use STDIN": `$1` is the first argument passed to your script, in your case, a file name. `<` means: write the file on the right side of the `<` to the `stdin` of the program on the left side. It's identical to `cat |`, just without the extra `cat` process.

Comment: Muller, oh, okay, I've seen both usages in the internet

Comment: yes, you've *seen* it; but that doesn't mean it's *good* to do `cat $1|…` where you could `… < $1`, as you can see from the fact that the former spawns an extra process with additional failure modes.

Comment: +1, especially for points 1 & 6.     `cat` vs `<` is quibbling about trivia - the overhead of an extra cat process might have been significant in PDP-11 days, but is irrelevant today.  Yes, there is some overhead, but it's negligible - unless they're `cat`-ing multi-gigabyte files, nobody needs to care about [UUOC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat).  Use whichever you prefer and ignore the 13373R-than-thou bullying.

Comment: @cas well, you're right about 2, I guess. It's less about overhead for me, though, it's about failure modes: it's pretty unlikely `cat` fails, admittedly. (In a scenario where the forking and execing of cat happens a couple million times and is in the same order of complexity as the database interaction, the overhead could become significant, but this is not the case here, I guess.)